# Implicitly virtual constexpr function

Tags: c++

Virtual functions cannot be `constexpr` however, when a function is implicitly virtual through inheritance, the compilers I have tried don't complain about it.

Here is a sample code:

```
class A
{
    virtual void doSomething() {}
};

class B : public A
{
    constexpr void doSomething() override {} // implicitly virtual constexpr
                                             // but no compilation error
};

class C : public A
{
    virtual constexpr void doSomething() override {} // explicitly virtual constexpr
                                                     // compilation error
};
```

I tried it with `gcc 7.2.0` and <s>`clang 5.0.0`</s>.

Are those compilers not compliant to the standard in this regard, or are implicitly virtual `constexpr` functions allowed ?

Comment: [This version of clang seems to complain](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3d1b1ef2348d2c2)

Comment: please double check clang

Comment: That is right, I was wrong about clang

Comment: and for GCC, even HEAD 8.0.0  doesn't compain

Comment: ideone seems to exhibit the problem (https://ideone.com/u3C5yz) unless you select the clang compiler (https://ideone.com/J2E2b2).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compilers have a bug. Note that this has been fixed in clang 3.5 already, not sure why you don't get an error, because I do.

The standard is pretty explicit about this in [[dcl.constexpr]p3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#3.1):

> The definition of a constexpr function shall satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - it shall not be virtual;
> - [...]

It does't matter whether `doSomething` is implicitly `virtual` or not. In both cases, it is considered to be `virtual`, and so it violates the point above.